# Fourier integral representations using only cosine functions.

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

Hi I have a question about Fourier integrals.
Can Fourier cosine integrals represent any function, or just even functions?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site. Usually to get the best quality answers it is a good idea to say where you have encountered the problem and to what level you understand the problem, so that responders can give sufficient information. Also, have you searched the site for any info on this topic already as this seems like quite a generic question? Further, do you mean Fourier series, rather than Fourier integrals?

Comment: @Dominic Michaelis "Fourier" should be capitalised, it is a proper noun. My edit was correct!!

Comment: @SimonHayward but you changed the title to "of even functions" but he wants to know if there is a Fourier cosine representation of functions which are not even

Comment: Fair enough, it seemed a little more precise since they were mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

An integral of the form $f(t) = \int \cos(\nu t) \hat f(\nu)\,d\nu$ is always an even function of $t$. Indeed,
$$f(-t) = \int \cos(-\nu t) \hat f(\nu)\,d\nu = \int \cos( \nu t) \hat f(\nu)\,d\nu = f(t)$$
Therefore, the cosine transform cannot represent a function that is not even.